# BigInteger.setBit and BigInteger.clearBit

Tags: java

Please take a look at the BigInteger.setBit source code :

```
public BigInteger setBit(int n) {
...
    int intNum = n >>> 5;
    int[] result = new int[Math.max(intLength(), intNum+2)];
```

then at BigInteger.clearBit source code :

```
public BigInteger clearBit(int n) {
...
    int intNum = n >>> 5;
    int[] result = new int[Math.max(intLength(), ((n + 1) >>> 5) + 1)];
```

Why the result length is n >>> 5 + 2 for setBit, but ((n + 1) >>> 5) + 1 for clearBit ?

Comment: The reason is that the leftmost bit must be 0 for positive number and 1 for negative number.

Comment: Suppose that we use 8 bits words to encode numbers.

-125 = 10000011, and becomes 00000011 = 3 if we clear the bit 7. To preserve the sign, we have to add a FF to the left : 11111111 00000011.
The formula for clearBit here is correct (n+1)/8 + 1 =  (7+1)/8 + 1 = 2 words.

Lets take now a positive number 131 = 00000000 10000011. It becomes negative if we set the bit 15 to 1 (10000000 10000011), so we have to add a 00 word to the left to preserve the sign: 00000000 10000000 10000011.
The formula for setBit n/8 + 2 = 15/8 + 2 = 3 is correct.